# how to execute a file/script when i save a file

Tags: bash, scripts, python3

for example;

```
#!/bin/python3
print("Hail Hydra")
```

so , how to execute this file without typing `python3 *filename.py` on my terminal when i save this

Comment: think it should be *#!/usr/bin/python3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First install inotify-tools using**

sudo apt-get install inotify-tools

**Now run**

inotifywait -q -m -e close_write --format %e test.py |
 while read events; do 
python3 test.py; 
done

**Where test.py is your python script**

Answer (score 1):

You could make it *executable* by issuing following command:

```
chmod u+x filename.py
```

Then you can run the script by entering

```
./filename.py
```

... where `./` just says that the file is in the current directory.

Comment: actually that's not what i asked but thanks for ur answer it helped me somehow